# Android Emulator Skin Layouts - Are there tools and a specification?

Tags: android, layout, android-emulator, skin, android-virtual-device

Skins for Android emulators are defined in a directory among /platforms/android-xxx/skins Additional vendor-specific skins also in the folder /add-ons). Here parts of the skin like images for backgournd and buttons are stored and a file that organizes these parts into the skin which is called layout.

The layout file contains a herarchical list of key-value pairs, defining parts and layouts. Here is a fragment as illustration:

```
display {
    width   480
    height  800
    x       32
    y       106
}

background {
    image htc-evo-4g.png
    x 0
    y 0
}

button {
    soft-left {
        image key.png
        x 191
        y 921
    }
    home {
        image key.png
        x 73
        y 921
    }
...
}
```

My questions are:

Is there a full specification of the language of the layout file?

Are there any tools to create skins, i.e. images and the layout files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android emulators are based on qemu.
You can find a simple document about skin layout file in (Android Source Dir)/external/qemu/docs/ANDROID-SKIN-FILES.TXT(I'm working with Android 2.3).

Or just go to [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_qemu/blob/master/docs/ANDROID-SKIN-FILES.TXT)