# Android Tablet Emulator Skins

Tags: android, android-emulator, tablet, skin

I'm looking for some recent Android **Tablet** Emulator **Skins**, like Galaxy Tab 10.1 or LG Slate.

Has anyone information about Tablet Skins?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I have found, but if you want to go to the effort you should be able to make your own using [the information in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233761/android-emulator-skin-layouts-are-there-tools-and-a-specification).